# Traditional axes in 3d Mathematica plots?

Tags: mathematica, computer-algebra-systems

Is there any way to tell Mathematica 7 to use "traditional" axes rather than boxing a three-dimensional graph?  That is, rather than the default view produced by

`Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},Boxed->False]`,
[image]

I would like three "axis arrows" to emanate from the origin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the end, I ended up writing my own arrow routine, which produces scalable arrowheads and scalable labels:

> `axes[x_, y_, z_, f_, a_] := 
>    Graphics3D[
>     Join[{Arrowheads[a]}, 
>      Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ {{x, 0, 0}, {0, y, 0}, {0, 0, 
>         z}}, {
>       Text[Style["x", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.9*x, 0.1*y, 0.1*z}], 
>       Text[Style["y", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.1 x, 0.9*y, 0.1*z}], 
>       Text[Style["z", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.1*x, 0.1*y, 0.9*z}]}]]`

The arguments are the x, y, and z positions of the x, y, and z arrows, respectively, f is the font scale (try about 0.05), and a is the arrowhead scale (about 0.05 should do it).  This is combined with ordinary 3D graphics using `Show[]`, as in

> `Show[Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Boxed -> False, 
>     PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7], Mesh -> 4, Axes -> None], 
>    axes[2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0.05, 0.02], 
>    PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {0, 1.5}}]`

The resulting plot is

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You need the AxesOrigin Option.

Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},Boxed->False, 
 AxesOrigin->{0,0,0}]

I misinterpreted your question in an earlier answer and I was suggesting using the "AxesEdge" Option which changes the sides of the bounding box on which the axes are displayed.  However, you might still find that useful:

Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Boxed -> False, 
AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}]

Comment: That's 50% of what I'm looking for - do you know if it's possible to cut off the negative bits, so that the axes are rays instead of lines?

Comment: @Josh Guffin: Do you need numbers on the axes?

Comment: In general no, but I would like them to be drawn by the system rather than adding them in by hand (with Graphics[] directives); I don't want to have to specify the length of the arrows _every_ time.

Comment: @Josh Guffin: Yes. You read my mind.  I think you can use the Scaled command to fix the size of relative size of the arrows.

Comment: "Traditional axes" to me sounds like the way mathematicians would typically sketch a 3D plot, no just with axes emanating from the origin, but with arrows at their positive ends and axis labels, too.